# Example of probability zero and expectation infinity.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, expectation

I seek an example that satisfies the following:
 $\mathbb{P}[A_k > 0 \: \: \: infinitely \: \: often] = 0$ However, $\mathbb{E}[A_k] = ∞$ for all $k$

where $A_k$ for $k>0$ are non-negative, independent R.V.s.

I thought perhaps Borel-Cantelli would be beneficial, but it doesn't seem like it would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about $(B_k)_{k\geq 1}$, $(C_k)_{k\geq 1}$ being respectively a sequence of independent Bernoulli random variables and a sequence of independent standard Cauchy random variables, with $B_k\sim\mathrm{Bern}\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)$; and letting $A_k \stackrel{\rm def}{=} B_k \lvert C_k\rvert$ for all $k\geq 0$?

Then: (i) $\mathbb{E}[A_k] = \frac{1}{k^2} \mathbb{E}[\lvert C_k\rvert] = \infty$ for all $k$, *but* (ii) $\mathbb{P}\{A_k>0\} = \frac{1}{k^2}$ for every $k$.

Applying Borel—Cantelly to $E_k\stackrel{\rm def}{=} \{ A_k > 0\}$ then shows that, since $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb{P} E_k < \infty$, we have $$\mathbb{P}\{A_k > 0 \text{ i.o.}\} = \mathbb{P}(\lim\sup_k E_k ) = 0.$$

Comment: Why is there a need for Cauchy R.V.s? Would Gaussian R.V.s work as well?

Comment: Those would be integrable: you want a non-negative r.v. with infinite expectation.

Comment: Any distribution that has infinite expectation will do for the $C_k$.

Comment: Exactly. My favorite one is Cauchy, so I went for that one.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation.